# Recursion manual tracing

Tags: c, recursion

I am learning recursion, some times it blow my mind.
I stacked on this code. I couldn't figure out how it is working.
Please someone explain me output.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sum(int n){

    int i;

    if(n==0)
        return;

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        printf(" %d ",n);
        sum(n-1);
    }
    printf("\n");

}


int main()
{
    sum(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with both C and C++? Which is it? Looks like C.

Comment: Hi welcome to stack overflow!  Which operating system are you using?  Do you have a debugger?

Comment: To learn recursion you must first learn recursion.

Comment: I know basic recursion.

Comment: So you have the base case. Now you need the inductive step :)

Comment: We are not a "explain my code" site.See [ask].

Comment: This is a very bad example to learn recursion. Everything inside it is Misleading, starting with the name `sum`. Change your teacher, or your book.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: In particular, please show us what you did to trace this yourself, how far you got, and what item got you stuck.  "I am stacked on this" is far too broad for us to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

In first call to sum(2) it will enter into the function then check if it is not 0 skip so enter for loop and now in first for iteration print 2 and call sum (1) ..just like above.. Now sum (1) will print 1 and again call sum(0) this time enter if condition and return to sum(1)state call now next for interation print current n i.e 0 call sum(-1) and which will print -1 call sum(-2) print -2 .....and so on... Infinite runtime....this thing is so messy :/